# Scala stackable traits

Tags: scala, traits

For the code below as I understand it linearization of expression

new E with D with C with B

is E -> C -> B -> D.  So then shouldnt the expression d.foo() in the code

below evaluate to ECBD instead of CBDE. What am I missing?

```
    trait A {
      def foo(): String = ""
    }

    trait B extends A {
      abstract override def foo() = "B" + super.foo()
    }

    trait C extends B {
      abstract override def foo() = "C" + super.foo()
    }

    trait D extends A {
      abstract override def foo() = "D" + super.foo()
    }

    class E extends A{
      override def foo() = "E"
    }

    var d = new E with D with C with B;
    d.foo() //prints CBDE
```

I have noticed that if I have a class F like below

```
class F extends A with D with C with B{
      override def foo() = "F" + super.foo()
}
```

and do

```
new F().foo
```

it prints "FCBD"

It seems a bit inconsistent to me because class F is mixed in the same way as the expression but has a different print order

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first case with `new E with D with C with B` is perfectly explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34243727/736957). Its linearization is `EDBC`, so when you call `d.foo()`, it

- first calls `C#foo()`,
- then `B#foo()`,
- then `D#foo()`
- and finally `E#foo()`.

If you make `E` a trait and mix it in the end: `val d = new D with C with B with E`, then `d.foo()` will return just `"E"`, because trait `E` is the "last" in the linearization and just overrides`foo`.

The case of `F` is different, because you define `foo` as `"F" + super.foo()`, and `super` in this case is `A with D with C with B` whose linearization is `ADBC`, so `new F().foo()` 
- first prints `"F"`, 
- then its `super.foo()` which is `"CBD"`.

By the way, try changing `A#foo()` to return `"A"`, then you will see that in `E` you override A's `foo` so `"A"` doesn't appear in the result, and in `F` it is `"FCBDA"`.

Comment: Just for further clarification, was it intentional that both D and B extended A?

Comment: I think yes, it forms the "diamond" shaped graph which is the cause of complexity for linearization here.

Answer (score 1):

So let's add some lines that show us instantiation order

```
  trait A {
    print("A")
    def foo(): String = "A"
  }

  trait B extends A {
    print("B")
    abstract override def foo() = "B" + super.foo()
  }

  trait C extends B {
    print("C")
    abstract override def foo() = "C" + super.foo()
  }

  trait D extends A {
    print("D")
    abstract override def foo() = "D" + super.foo()
  }

  class E extends A {
    print("E")
    override def foo() = "E" + super.foo()
  }

  var e = new E with D with C with B
  println()
  println(s"e >> ${e.foo()}")
```

printed:

`AEDBC
e >> CBDEA`

but what with `F`?

```
  class F extends A with D with C with B {
    print("F")
    override def foo() = "F" + super.foo()
  }
  val f = new F()
  println()
  println(s"f >> ${f.foo()}")
```

printed:

`ADBCF
f >> FCBDA`

As You can see the linearization for both cases different!
When we instantiate the class with a cortege of traits it's not the same as when we create a separate class that inherits those traits.

So the order of calling `foo` different too, according to linearization.
And it's a little bit clear when we add `super.foo()` to the `E`