# What is the issue with below Scala code snippet?

Tags: scala, inheritance, traits

I am facing issue with the code snippet, it says there is a conflict for func function in traits A and B

//Tried the below code:

```
trait A{
  def func(): Unit = {
    println("Inside trait A")
  }
}
trait B{
 def func(): Unit = {
    println("Inside trait B")
  }
}
class C extends A with B{
 //super[A].func()
}
object Sample extends App{
  val ob = new C()
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

The error is

```
class C inherits conflicting members:
  def func(): Unit (defined in trait A) and
  def func(): Unit (defined in trait B)
  (note: this can be resolved by declaring an `override` in class C.)
```

You can override the member as the error message suggests:

```
class C extends A with B {
  override def func(): Unit = super[A].func() // Inside trait A
}
```

or

```
class C extends A with B {
  override def func(): Unit = super[B].func() // Inside trait B
}
```

If you don't specify any parent trait in `super[...]` then the choice of method implementation will depend on the order of parents:

```
class C extends A with B {
  override def func(): Unit = super.func() // Inside trait B
}
```

or

```
class C extends B with A {
  override def func(): Unit = super.func() // Inside trait A
}
```

[Linearization order in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34242536/linearization-order-in-scala)

[Scala stackable traits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40579694/scala-stackable-traits)