# Why methods of traits are called when a class has method's implementation

Tags: scala

In following code, why does method `A1` of traits `C` and `D` are called even though class B has defined `A1`?

```
scala> trait A {
     | def A1 = A2
     | def A2 //A2 is abstract and need implementation
     | }
defined trait A

scala> class B extends A {
     | def A2 = println("B") //implemented A2 in B
     | }
defined class B

scala> val b1 = new B
b1: B = B@163e8949
```

this works fine.

```
scala> b1.A1
B

scala> b1.A2
B
```

now I mix traits. C still has A2 abstract

```
scala> trait C extends A {
     | abstract override def A1 = {super.A1; C}
     | def C = println("C")
     | }
defined trait C
```

D still has A2 abstract **strong text**

```
scala> trait D extends A {
     | abstract override def A1 = {super.A1; D}
     | def D = println("D")
     | }
defined trait D
```

Why C and D are printed when I cam calling A1 of B. Shouldn't B's A1 only call B's A2 which is implemented to print B?

scala> val b2 = new B with C with D

```
b2: B with C with D = $anon$1@701d2b59

scala> b2.A1
B
C
D

scala> b2.A2
B

scala> val b3 = new B with D  with C
b3: B with D with C = $anon$1@270f28cf

scala> b3.A1
B
D
C
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Also look at how [trait linearizazion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34242536/linearization-order-in-scala) works in Scala. Examples work perfectly fine.

Comment: want to understand how traits are called. I think I have got a hint now

Comment: A `def` in trait w/o type, `def` w/ same name (still no type) no `override`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose what I am using is called stackable trait pattern. Basically, if I use `new B with C with D` and call a method, compiler will see if the method is defined in D, then C and then B (order is right to left). When the compiler sees an implementation it uses it. The use of `super` makes the compiler call the next implementation available in the class or trait on left (again right to left order)

Removed `super` calls.

```
scala> trait D extends A {
     | abstract override def A1 = { D}
     | def D = println("D")
     | }
defined trait D

scala> trait C extends A {
     | abstract override def A1 = {  C }
     | def C = println("C")
     | }
defined trait C

scala> val b3 = new B with D  with C
b3: B with D with C = $anon$1@7417ef4f
```

As `super` is removed, when compiler sees call to `A1`, it checks `C` first (rightmost, order is right to left) and it finds `A1` and uses that implementation. As `A1` no longer uses super, `A1` in `D` or `B` are not called.

```
scala> b3.A1
C
```

If `D` is rightmost then only `D`'s `A1` is called

```
scala> val b3 = new B with C with D
b3: B with C with D = $anon$1@fd4459b

scala> b3.A1
D
```

Added `super` after print. This changes order or printing.

```
scala> trait C extends A {
     | abstract override def A1 = {  C ; super.A1}
     | def C = println("C")
     | }
defined trait C

scala> val b3 = new B with C with D
b3: B with C with D = $anon$1@4489f60f

scala> b3.A1
D
```

As `super` is called, after calling `A1` from D, compiler looks for `A1` of super class (next one on left) and keeps going towards left.

```
scala> val b3 = new B with D with C
b3: B with D with C = $anon$1@7b3c0ecb

scala> b3.A1
C
D

scala>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why C and D are printed when I cam calling A1 of B. Shouldn't B's A1 only call B's A2 which is implemented to print B?

No. `super.A1` refers to `A#A1`, which calls `A2` of the object it's called on: not `B#A2`, not `A#A2`, but `this.A2`.

Also, `C` and `D` aren't related to `B` in any way, so they couldn't be calling `B#A1` in any case: did you mean `class C/D extends B`?