# Control parent's function calls--diamond issue?

Tags: scala

In the code below, if I print DDD().hey() I'll see the inside '9' then the output of 1.  Read somewhere that's because BBB was the last trait mixed in.

Is three a way to control this vs convention?  For example what if I want to force CCC's hey() to happen instead of BBB's (without just swapping the mixin orderings)?

```
trait AAA {
  def hey(): Int  
}

trait BBB extends AAA {
  override def hey(): Int = 1
}

trait CCC extends AAA {  
  override def hey(): Int = 5
}

case class DDD() extends CCC with BBB {
  override def hey(): Int = 9

  def test(): Int = {
    println("Inside: "+hey())
    super.hey()  // Can I control what 'super' means?  BBB or CCC?
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can:

```
super[CCC].hey() // 5
super[BBB].hey() // 1
```

You might also want to read about [linearization order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34242536/linearization-order-in-scala).