# How is scala linearizing this?

Tags: scala

I'm working my way through Odersky's Programming in Scala and I'm looking at the chapter on traits. He gives an example where various traits/classes are linearized and says this:

```
Cat -> FourLegged -> HasLegs -> Furry -> Animal -> AnyRef -> Any
```

> When any of these classes and traits invokes a method via super, the 
>       implementation invoked will be the first implementation to its right in 
>       the linearization.

I've defined classes/traits as follows:

```
abstract class Animal { def hi }

class Cat extends Animal { def hi { println("cat") } }

trait Furry extends Animal { abstract override def hi { 
  println("furry"); super.hi } }
```

and done

```
val c = new Cat with Furry
c.hi
```

and I get

```
furry
cat
```

According to the book, the super in furry should call `Animal.hi` Since Animal is abstract, that should either cause a compile error or a runtime error I would have thought. Instead it calls `cat.hi` What am I missing? I thought the Cat class would appear first in the linearization, and therefore there is no way that a `super` call could call it?

(I missed out HasLegs and FourLegged to keep it simpler)

I suspect they've mis-stated the linearization order?

Thanks!

EDIT: Following user2357112's comment below, I tried mixing in the Furry trait statically:

```
scala> class Cat extends Animal with Furry { def hi { println("cat") } }
<console>:13: error: overriding method hi in trait Furry of type => Unit;
 method hi needs `override' modifier
       class Cat extends Animal with Furry { def hi { println("cat") } }
```

I'm now rather confused as I thought that it didn't make a difference whether you mixed in a trait at runtime or in the code. But here, the runtime mixin executes without error, but I get a compile error if I try to mix it in in code. What gives?

Comment: The book's `Cat` is `class Cat extends Animal with Furry with Fourlegged`. `with Furry` is already part of `Cat`.

Comment: Thanks @user2357112 - why would that make a difference? I thought that mixing in during runtime would be the same as mixing in statically as part of the build step?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34243727/2093695), the concrete class will be constructed first when using mixins, and linearization order is the opposite of construction order. Therefore, the construction is `Animal -> Cat -> Furry`, and the linearization is `Furry -> Cat -> Animal`, which is why you see "furry" first and "cat" second.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure what you say makes sense. If the concrete class is constructed first, and linearization is the opposite order, then surely the concrete class - Cat - should come first, but you have it between Furry and Animal?

Comment: @Bruce The construction proceeds `Any -> AnyRef -> Animal -> Cat -> Furry`. The linearization order is `Furry -> Cat -> Animal -> AnyRef -> Any`.