# How to let trait use `this` constructor in scala?

Tags: scala, traits, self-type, f-bounded-polymorphism, return-current-type

[edit update] this is a proper statment of my problem.

I hope to call the constructor inside a `trait`.
But it seems I have to use `apply` function. does it exist usage like new this()?

Like the code below. It throws type mismatch. I hope to add constraint of constructor, or I have to use `apply` function.

```
  trait B { this:C =>
    def values:Seq[Int]
    def apply(ints:Seq[Int]):this.type
    def hello:this.type = apply( values map (_ + 1) )
  }

  trait C

  class A(val v:Seq[Int]) extends C with B{
    override def values: Seq[Int] = v

    override def apply(ints: Seq[Int]): A.this.type = new A(ints)
  }
```

Comment: it would be good to understand trait linearization order/rules. there is a good answer to explain that https://stackoverflow.com/a/34243727/1331769

Comment: @VikasPandya Issue here is not with linearization. It's just type mismatch. It's the same for both `C with B` and `B with C`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this.type` is the type of this specific instance. So you can write

```
override def hello = this
```

but you can't write

```
override def hello = new A()
```

since `A` is a supertype of `this.type`.

Probably you wanted

```
trait B { this: C =>
  type This <: B /*or B with C*/
  def hello: This
}

trait C

class A extends C with B {
  type This = A
  override def hello = new A()
}
```

Or maybe even

```
trait B { self: C =>
  type This >: self.type <: B with C { type This = self.This }
  def hello: This
}
```

*Returning the "Current" Type in Scala* https://tpolecat.github.io/2015/04/29/f-bounds.html

Comment: I update the question, previous one doesn't reflect constructor.

Comment: @worldterminator Nothing changed. As I've already answered you can't assign a value of type `A` to a variable of type `A.this.type` since type `A` is a supertype of `A.this.type` and not vice versa.

Comment: is there any way to call constructor of A in trait? like this(params), I didn't find such syntax

Comment: @worldterminator You used proper syntax for constructor `new A(ints)`. `new this(params)` is illegal. `this(params)` is `this.apply(params)`. `new this(params)` is senseless, `this` is the only instanse. If you want new instance of `A` you should do `new A(params)`. You just can't assign this value to variable of type `A.this.type`. Type `A.this.type` is wrong here.

Comment: @worldterminator When you do `new A(ints)` you return `A`, not `A.this.type`.