# C# interface with default method vs traits

Tags: c#, scala, functional-programming

In the Scala doc, https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/traits.html, it gives an example of trait.

```
trait Iterator[A] {
  def hasNext: Boolean
  def next(): A
}

class IntIterator(to: Int) extends Iterator[Int] {
  private var current = 0
  override def hasNext: Boolean = current < to
  override def next(): Int = {
    if (hasNext) {
      val t = current
      current += 1
      t
    } else 0
  }
}


val iterator = new IntIterator(10)
iterator.next()  // returns 0
iterator.next()  // returns 1
```

We know C# doesn't support traits yet. However, the example above can be easily converted to C# code:

```
interface Iterator<A> 
{ 
    bool HasNext(); 
    A Next(); 
}

public class IntIterator : Iterator<int> 
{
    int _to;
    int _current = 0;
    public IntIterator(int to) => _to = to;
    public bool HasNext() => _current < _to;
    public int Next() => HasNext() ? _current++ : 0;
}

var itor = new IntIterator(10);
itor.Next()
```

And C# interface can have default method now. What's C# missing comparing with traits?

Or there should be a better Scala example to show the power of trait?

Comment: @Renat No, they aren't.

Answer (score 3):

Comparing with Scala traits in particular (traits in different languages can be quite different), C# is missing:

1. Initialization code: you can have

   ```
   trait A {
     println("A's constructor")
   }
   ```

   and this code will be executed (in proper order) in the constructor of any class inheriting from `A`. Or more simply

   ```
   trait A {
     val x = 10
   }
   ```
2. [Trait linearization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34242536/linearization-order-in-scala) (at least in the specific details)
3. Different `base` (in C#)/`super` (in Scala) resolution, which means the [Stackable Trait](https://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/stackable_trait_pattern.html) pattern won't work with C# interfaces.
4. (coming in Scala 3) [Constructor parameters](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/other-new-features/trait-parameters.html)
5. (removed in Scala 3) [Early definitions](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/05-classes-and-objects.html#early-definitions)

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you can do something like traits in C#.  Traits is ad-hoc polymorphism. i.e. you can gift types with additional *traits* ad-hoc, or after-the-fact.  This is useful when you're given a type (like `IEnumerable<T>` from the BCL) and you want it to have additional properties, like being a monad (but you don't own the type, so you can't change its interface list).

So, for your iterator example, you could do this:

```
public interface Iterator<MA, A>
{
    bool HasNext(MA iter);
    A Next(MA iter);
}
```

`MA` is the container type, `A` is what it contains.

Next, we'll do an implementation of that for `IEnumerator<A>`.

```
public struct IteratorEnum<A> : Iterator<IEnumerator<A>, A>
{
    public bool HasNext(IEnumerator<A> iter) =>
        iter.MoveNext();

    public A Next(IEnumerator<A> iter) =>
        iter.Current;
}
```

> Ignore the fact that `MoveNext` / `HasNext`, and `Next` / `Current` don't mean the same thing, this is just for convenience.

Note how the type is a `struct`.  This is because structs can never be `null`.  And so, `default(MY_STRUCT)` will always have a non-null value.

Now, we'll create a generic implementation that uses `Iterator` and knows nothing about the underlying type:

```
public static IEnumerable<A> IterAnything<IterA, MA, A>(MA iter) 
    where IterA : struct, Iterator<MA, A>
{
    while(default(IterA).HasNext(iter))
    {
        yield return default(IterA).Next(iter);
    }
}
```

Note the use of `default(IterA)`, this is because we've constrained `IterA` to be `struct, Iterator<MA, A>` - that means it can't be `null` and must implement `Iterator<MA, A>`.

Then we can invoke it with any `Iterator` we like:

```
var items = (new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }).AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator();

var newitems = IterAnything<IteratorEnum<int>, IEnumerator<int>, int>(items);
```

A simpler example of this approach is to `Num<A>` and `Eq<A>`.  There is no base `INumeric` type in C#, but we want to write our numeric processing functions once.  The types are all buried in the BCL, so we can't go and change their interfaces:

```
public interface Num<A>
{
    A Add(A lhs, A rhs);
    A Subtract(A lhs, A rhs);
    A Multiply(A lhs, A rhs);
    A Divide(A lhs, A rhs);
    A FromInt(int value);
    A One { get; }
    A Zero { get; }
}

public interface Eq<A>
{
    bool IsEqualTo(A lhs, A rhs);

    // using C#8 default interface methods
    bool IsNoEqualTo(A lhs, A rhs) => !IsEqualTo(lhs, rhs); 
}
```

Then we can implement both for `int` and `long`:

```
public struct NumInt : Num<int>, Eq<int>
{
    public int Add(int lhs, int rhs) => lhs + rhs;
    public int Subtract(int lhs, int rhs) => lhs - rhs;
    public int Multiply(int lhs, int rhs) => lhs * rhs;
    public int Divide(int lhs, int rhs) => lhs / rhs;
    public int FromInt(int value) => value;
    public bool IsEqualTo(int lhs, int rhs) => lhs == rhs;
    public int One => 1;
    public int Zero => 0;
}

public struct NumLong : Num<long>, Eq<long>
{
    public long Add(long lhs, long rhs) => lhs + rhs;
    public long Subtract(long lhs, long rhs) => lhs - rhs;
    public long Multiply(long lhs, long rhs) => lhs * rhs;
    public long Divide(long lhs, long rhs) => lhs / rhs;
    public long FromInt(int value) => (long)value;
    public bool IsEqualTo(long lhs, long rhs) => lhs == rhs;
    public long One => 1;
    public long Zero => 0;
}
```

Then we can create some methods for working with numbers:

```
public static bool IsEqualTo0<NumA, A>(A n) where NumA : struct, Num<A>, Eq<A> =>
    default(NumA).IsEqualTo(n, default(NumA).Zero);

public static bool IsEqualTo1<NumA, A>(A n) where NumA : struct, Num<A>, Eq<A> =>
    default(NumA).IsEqualTo(n, default(NumA).One);

public static A Subtract1<NumA, A>(A n) where NumA : struct, Num<A>, Eq<A> =>
    default(NumA).Subtract(n, default(NumA).One);

public static A Subtract2<NumA, A>(A n) where NumA : struct, Num<A>, Eq<A> =>
    Subtract1<NumA, A>(Subtract1<NumA, A>(n));

public static A Fibonacci<NumA, A>(A n) where NumA : struct, Num<A>, Eq<A> =>
    IsEqualTo0<NumA, A>(n) || IsEqualTo1<NumA, A>(n)
        ? n
        : Fibonacci<NumA, A>(default(NumA).Add(
                                Subtract1<NumA, A>(n), 
                                Subtract2<NumA, A>(n)));
```

And then finally, invoke:

```
Fibonacci<NumInt, int>(100);
Fibonacci<NumLong, long>(100L);
```

And so, that shows adding traits to a type ad-hoc.  It's not pretty, and the C# team are looking to address this with the Shapes/Concepts/.. proposal.  But, it is possible if you need it.  I use it every now and then, and have [a ton of example traits and implementations in my language-ext library](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext) (called Type-classes and Class-instances).

> If the .NET team had made an `INumeric` interface and made all the numeric types derive from it, then usage of it would cause boxing.  The approach demonstrated above doesn't cause any boxing at all.  Also, all the `default(NumA)` calls get optimised out in a release build, so it's just as fast as calling the functions directly.

The limitations are that C# doesn't have higher kinds, which leads to problems when trying to implement something like `Monad` or `Functor`, but [types like `Monoid` are easy](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext/blob/master/LanguageExt.Core/TypeClasses/Monoid/Monoid.cs)