# What is wrong with the below inheritance code in Scala?

Tags: scala

Whats wrong with the below code snippet,
is this related to diamond problem ?
When i try to call the function func with D's instance I am facing run time error

```
trait B{
  def func(): Unit = {
    println("Inside class B")
  }
}

trait C{
  def func(): Unit = {
    println("Inside class C")
  }
}

class D extends B with C{
}


object ABC extends App{
  val ob = new D
  ob.func()
}
```

Comment: The code doesn't compile in Scala 2.13 or 3. I doubt you're getting a runtime error.

Comment: Consider [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34242536/linearization-order-in-scala). There is a good explanation as for me.

Comment: What behaviour do you expect?

Answer (score 3):

Well, as written, `B.func` and `C.func` are *unrelated*, so when you do `D extends B with C`, it ends up having two unrelated members with the same name - thus the error.

A naive attempt to fix this, would be to add a common parent:

```
trait A { def func(): Unit }
trait B extends A { def func() = println("B") }
trait C extends A { def func() = println("C") }

class D extends B with C
```

Surprisingly, this does not compile either (which to me seems like it's a bug in the compiler ), but if you just add `override` to the declarations (which is not required and *should* not make any difference), *then* it will:

```
trait A { def func(): Unit }
trait B extends A { override def func() = println("B") }
trait C extends A { override def func() = println("C") }

class D extends B with C
```

**Update** Ok, maybe, I I need to relax my rant about "bug in the compiler" a little bit, and downgrade it to "obscure and weird behavior" :) It looks like only the declaration in `C` needs the `override` in this case, `B` can go without ... this *kinda* sorta makes *a little bit* of sense: `C`'s `func` in `D` overrides a concrete implementation (from `B`), which makes `override` required ... If the compiler error actually mentioned this, I would be willing to go further and downgrade "obscure and weird behvaior" to "unnecessary boilerplate requirement" :)